# Functions without arguments

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

In the course of a project recently I had to use a particular function `u[x, t]` a number of times.  Because in mathematics I would typically write this function as $u$, without arguments, it so happened that I often mistyped `u` for `u[x, t]` in my code, leading to a lot of confusion and frustration when the code wouldn't work.

What I'd like to know is whether there's any way to tell Mathematica to use `u` as a synonym of `u[x, t]`, or in some other way understand that the quantity `u` is a function of `x` and `t`, in the same way as it would if I defined it explicitly (*e.g.* as `u := x/t`).

I'm sure someone must have asked this question before, but because I'm not sure what to call this I'm not sure how to look for it.

Comment: I recommend against it. Explicitly defining your variable dependence is important in the context of MMA (e.g. when taking derivatives etc). Many conventions that may be clear from context to a human reader can lead to confusion when a computer is looking at it.

Comment: @Simon yep that covers it, thank you!  How do I mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: You're welcome! The powers that be will likely mark it shortly. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Hmm @Simon I appear to have some trouble getting your answer in that thread to work for me — everything's fine until I DeclareSymbolicFunction.  Once I've done that any input I give mathematica returns replaceSymbFuncs[<input>], even for very basic commands like Clear["Global`*"].  I suspect the issue might be somewhere in the HoldAll definition of replaceSymbFuncs.  Do you have any advice?  I'm on mma 11.3 if that helps.

Comment: I don't have V11.3 running, but it works for me in versions 10 and 12. From your description, it sounds like the function replaceSymbFuncs did not get properly defined. Try again quitting the kernel and then running the code block from the other answer before doing any other calculations.

Comment: @Simon That's fixed it, thank you!  And I was so sure I'd already tried turning it off and back on again...

Comment: Sure. Actually, the ``Clear["Global`*"]`` was likely the problem. It clears the definition of `replaceSymbFuncs`, but doesn't clear the definition of `$Pre`, because `$Pre` is in the ``System` `` context. Personally, I always just quit the kernel rather than attempting  ``Clear["Global`*"]``.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`InputAutoReplacements`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html) to create a document which automatically replaces `u` with `u[x,t]`:

`nb = CreateDocument[{}, InputAutoReplacements -> {"u" -> "u[x,t]"}];`

Comment: Won't this be an issue if I do at some point type u[x, t], e.g. to input specific arguments?  In any case I think the answer linked by Simon Rochester is a good way to go. ;)